# Graph not obeying first derivative test

Tags: calculus, derivatives, algebraic-curves

We have,

$$y= 2x-3x^{2/3}$$

Putting $y'=0$ yields $x=1$, however the function has three intervals breaking at 1 and 0. My question is that how is the curve falling between 0 and 1 if the first derivative doesn't allow it?

Answer (score 1):

The function is not differentiable at $0$. So the behavior just below zero and just above zero could be quite different (and in this case, they are quite different).

Comment: Is there a method to algebraically interpret the curve or we have to rely on function plotters to see how the curve behaves in the neighborhood of such points?

Comment: Sure. You can compute the derivative every except at $0$. This means you know exactly where the function is increasing and decreasing, except at $0$. I'm not sure how you go about it, but when I teach Calc I my students make number lines with "critical points" and intervals of increasing/decreasing marked [they do this when they learn curve-sketching]. Combined with you ability to simple see what $y(0)$ is, there is no need for anything special to examine this function.